# OpenGl rotating triangles have some bad effects

Tags: c++, opengl, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I wrote a code to draw 10 yellow triangles on the screen and rotate them to animate like this I will add 2 frames below:[image: frame 1]  [image: frame 2]

All this is very nice, but when I add number of rectangles to be about 800 then I see this:

[image: open gl cannot handle 800 triangles 1].

In the case when I have 500 triangles I see the following problems:

[image: 500 triangles problem 1] [image: 500 triangles problem 2] [image: 500 triangles problem 3] [image: 500 triangles problem 4]

As you can see I don't even have those colors. (I have only black and the yellow one.) Actually, you can see there any color, depending on the number of triangles. I think this is some OpenGL problem. I an new to OpenGL and I guess I misused something in OpenGL. Here is the code. It is in cocos2d-x (C++) but surely you can understand what is being done here:

```
Color4F color1e(239.0f / 255, 255.0f / 255, 138.0f / 255, 1);

auto sunNode = DrawNode::create();
sunNode->setContentSize(_size);

int bansCount = 1000;
Vec2 center(_size / 2);

float angleStep = (2 * 3.1415926) / bansCount;

auto rotated = [angleStep, center](float mult) {
Vec2 vc(0, 0);
vc.rotate(center, angleStep * mult);
return vc - center;
};

for(int i = 0; i < bansCount; i+=2) {
   sunNode->drawTriangle(
   Vec2(0,0), // vertex 1
    rotated(i), // vertex 2
    rotated(i + 1), // vertex 3
    color1e // color of vertices
);
}

addChild(sunNode, 2); // add to sceen
sunNode->setPosition(center); // position on center

// infinitely rotate 
sunNode->runAction(RepeatForever::create(RotateBy::create(0.05, 3.1415926 / 10)));
```

Code full is here, in case someone want to look at or experiment: https://github.com/jonyrock/Cocos2dxDrawingArtifacts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interference pattern is normal, and it happens because edges are quantized (to a pixel or to some sub-pixel fixed value) and steps create those interference patterns with a much lower frequency than the step frequency itself.

The color is not normal, and I can think to two possibilities:

- Using non-saturated RGB colors and "cleartype"-like technology that tries to use separate subpixel led intesity values to improve resolution (and this could interact with the interference patterns)
- A bug

If it's the first case then using pure red, pure green or pure blue like

```
Color4F color1e(255.0f / 255, 0.0f / 255, 0.0f / 255, 1); // Pure red
```

shouldn't introduce extra colors.

Comment: thanks for your response. My problem is the colors I should not see. But except "bug" I could not understand what you meant. :) Sorry, I am really new and I don't know what is subpixel, what is clearview, what is non-saturated RGB. More simpler what can cause this problem? And how can fix this?

Comment: @Narek: sorry... the microsoft name for this idea was "cleartype" not "clearview". It's the use of different values of R, G and B even when rendering grayscale graphics to improve spatial resolution.

Comment: I should mention that this is OpenGL ES and it happens of iOS, Android and Linux. I hope this info can tell you something more.

Comment: @Narek: Then IMO we're left with option 2 :-D

Comment: You are absolutely correct! Here is the bug report: http://www.cocos2d-x.org/issues/5573 I have tried without using `DrawNode` and it worked.

Comment: The color patterns are really... interesting. @Narek: Can you try calling `glDisable(GL_DITHER)` before you start rendering? I wonder if that might change anything.

Answer (score 0):

The patterns you see are clearly a result of the pattern you're trying to draw having a finer structure than the display can resolve (i.e. you're violating the so called Nyquist Limit). This results in so called "aliasing Moire" patterns. The colors you see could be the result of blending artifacts in the aliasing pattern, or if antialiasing is enabled by bleeding into the subpixels (where the pixel structure of the monitor is used to artificially increase the resolution). Anyway, the problem arises from the fact, that your pattern has a higher spatial resolution, than the target framebuffer can resolve.

Comment: Mind, linking the technical terms?

Comment: @Domi: Mind using Google? Sorry, but there are so many texts on each single term, that I don't see a reason to put very specific links to each term.